# Kotlin: How to change text and color of button, when click?

Tags: android, kotlin, button, onclick

I want to change color and text of a button when click the button, without using ToogleButton.
And I set the xml file like this.

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/downloadButton"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Download"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

And I made a code in the main Activity is,

```
 override fun onDownloadClick(item: ProjectListDataModel, position: Int) {
       downloadButton.setOnClickListener {
            if (downloadButton.getText() == "Download") {
                downloadButton.setText("Downloaded")
                downloadButton.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.blue))
            } else if (downloadButton.getText() == "Downloaded") {
                downloadButton.setText("Download")
                downloadButton.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.gray))
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is the Adopter

```
class ServerProjectsRecyclerAdapter(
    val list:List<ProjectListDataModel>,
    var serverClickListener: ServerProjectListActivity) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ServerProjectRecyclerViewHolder>() {

    interface OnProjectListClickListener {
        fun onServerProjectListClick(item: ProjectListDataModel, position: Int)
        fun onDownloadClick(item: ProjectListDataModel, position: Int)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ServerProjectRecyclerViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_cardview_server, parent, false)
        return ServerProjectRecyclerViewHolder(view)

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.count()
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ServerProjectRecyclerViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.initialize(list.get(position), serverClickListener)
    }
}

class ServerProjectRecyclerViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    fun initialize(
        item: ProjectListDataModel,
        action: ServerProjectListActivity
    ) {
        itemView.projectListView.text = item.name
        itemView.modifiedTimeText.text = item.modTime
        //itemView.descriptionText.text = item.description
        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            action.onServerProjectListClick(item, adapterPosition)
        }
        itemView.downloadButton.setOnClickListener {
            action.onDownloadClick(item, adapterPosition)
        }
    }
}
```

it seems no errors, but not working.
There are some example using java, but not Kotlin.

Here is the java tutorial what I want to do.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OVmLLet9aAQ

Dose anyone know what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here change your interface with this.

```
interface OnProjectListClickListener {
  fun onServerProjectListClick(item: ProjectListDataModel, position: Int)
  fun onDownloadClick(button:Button,item: ProjectListDataModel, position: Int)
}
```

change the following in your `viewholder` class

```
itemView.downloadButton.setOnClickListener {
            action.onDownloadClick(it,item, adapterPosition)
        }
```

and finally in your activity do the following.

```
 override fun onDownloadClick(button:Button,item: ProjectListDataModel, position: Int) {

    if (button.getText() == "Download") {
      button.setText("Downloaded")
      button.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.blue))
    } else if (button.getText() == "Downloaded") {
      button.setText("Download")
      button.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.gray))
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks! Actually, the button is in the list of RecyclerView. So, I linked to the viewholder in recycler view Adapter. But, a problem is it was applied at the first list of recyclerview only. Do you know why?  I fixed the question.

Comment: `itemView.downloadButton.setOnClickListener` this is in the viewholder.

Comment: Wow...YOU ARE LEGEND!!!! hahaha~ it works! thanks you so much! Additionally, the view holder class should be `action.onDownloadClick(it as Button,item, adapterPosition)`. Anyways it was so helpful! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

#### This is the property you should use:

```
android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
```

### Change your onClickListener as below:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_server_project_list)

    downloadButton?.setOnClickListener {
        if (downloadButton.getText() == "Download") {
            downloadButton.setText("Downloaded")
            downloadButton.setBackgroundTint(android.R.color.black)
        } else if (downloadButton.getText() == "Downloaded") {
            downloadButton.setText("Download")
            downloadButton.setBackgroundTint(android.R.color.holo_red_dark)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, mate. I changed but there's an error `downloadButton.setBackgroundTint(android.R.color.holo_red_dark)` here. "unsolved reference setBackgroundTint"

Comment: refer to this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList)